# Chrome console: How to display the correct object type?

Tags: jquery, debugging, google-chrome

When I have some labels in my HTML and I am getting their content with

```
$.("label").contents()
```

Chrome displays an array which looks like a string array:

```
["text1", "text2"]
```

although these are actually jquery objects. Furthermore

```
$.("label").contents()[0]
```

outputs

```
"text1"
```

When I am using a "typeof" in front of the above code, I am just getting "object" in both cases. I just spent a while figuring out what objects really are in the array and had to guess some of their members. Usually Chrome displays objects as an expandable tree view. Why not in this case? How could I force it?

Comment: may be `console.log($(label))`

Comment: Thanks. It works in some cases. Will be useful for me in the future.